# NHibernate: Multiple mappings to a single table

Tags: nhibernate, mapping

I have a class that I would like to map to a single table in two different ways, for privacy reasons.  Let's say the class looks like this:

```
class Person
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   // ... many other properties omitted ...
}
```

And the corresponding database table looks like this:

```
create table Person
(
   ID int not null,
   RealName nvarchar(512) not null,
   FakeName nvarchar(512) not null,
   -- many other columns omitted
)
```

The two mappings I need are:

- From **Name** property to **RealName** column
- From **Name** property to **FakeName** column

All other properties should be mapped the same in both cases. I strongly prefer not to have to repeat the mappings for these other properties.

I have tried several different approaches with no luck. Using **<union-subclass>** to isolate the different mappings fails with this error: *DuplicateMappingException: Duplicate table mapping Person*. I could create two distinct database views, and map to them separately in order to avoid the duplicate table mapping error, but that is not preferable.

Using an **"entity-name"** attribute to specify the mappings is tempting, but is poorly documented and seems to have some major drawbacks: a) it requires me to repeat all the other mappings for both entities, and b) it is not compatible with <many-to-one> relationships from other classes that refer to the Person class.

Is there a good way to do this that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use NHibernate formula Attribute to match the Name Property as follows

```
<property name="Name" formula="(SELECT id,(CASE WHEN yourcondition then RealName else FakeName end) as Name FROM Person)"/>
```

Formula you can ref - http://blog.khedan.com/2009/01/eager-loading-from-formula-in.html

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but I don't think it will work for me because there is no condition I can test from within SQL to determine the correct mapping. I need to control the mapping from within the application layer.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I suppose that the OP has solved his problem in some way, I'd like to propose a solution using projections.

Basically, in your data access layer (DAL) you choose a slightly more complicated way to access your data using a list of projections but get back instances of the desired `FakePerson` or `RealPerson` class depending on your logic.

It would look something like this:

```
FakePerson alias = null;
var person = _session.QueryOver<Person>()
    .SelectList(list => list
        .Select(go => go.Id).WithAlias(() => alias.Id)
        .Select(go => go.FakeName).WithAlias(() => alias.Name) // <- the trick
        .Select(go => go.Other).WithAlias(() => alias.Other)
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<FakePerson>());
```

You would still map your `Person` class with both properties `FakeName` and `RealName` but make them `protected` and derive `FakePerson` and `RealPerson` from Person with a public `Name` property.

I realize that you still have to list all properties twice now, it has just moved from the mapping to the DAL. Well, maybe this helps someone out there, anyways.